# apps updates with previously clicked info- react and redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux

Problem is when i click on edit button, they fill the text inputs with the previously clicked info. when i check my store, the right object is placed into my editor object. so I don't know what's wrong

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';
import {get_contact, update_contact} from '../actions/';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';

class Edit extends Component {
 constructor(props){
  super(props);
   this.state = {// constructor and initialization of my state
     namex: '',
     emailx: '',
     phonex: '',
     idx: ''
  }
    this.nameInput = React.createRef();
    this.emailInput = React.createRef(); //creating references for inputs
    this.phoneInput = React.createRef();
}

componentDidMount(){
 let id_1 =this.props.location.id;
  this.props.get_contact(id_1);
   const {id,name, email, phone} = this.props.edits;
    this.setState({
     namex: name,
     emailx: email, //fetching info from props
     phonex: phone,
      idx: id
      })
  }

  submit_handler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({
      name: this.nameInput.current.value,
      email: this.emailInput.current.value,// accessing input values
      phone: this.phoneInput.current.value
    })
    // this.props.update_contact(this.state);
    // this.setState({
    //   name: '',
    //   email: '',
    //   phone: '',
    //   id: ''
    // }) console.log(this.state)

  }   render(){

const {id,namex, emailx, phonex} = this.state;
return (
  <div>
  <div className = "ml-20 mt-10 " style = {{width: '500px', marginLeft: '400px',marginTop: '80px'}}>
   <h3 className="display-4 text-center">Edit Contacts </h3>
  <form onSubmit = {this.submit_handler.bind(this)}>

  <div className = "form-group">
  <label htmlFor ="Names">Names</label>
  <input className="form-control" type="text" name="name" defaultValue={namex} ref = {this.nameInput}/>
  </div>
  <div className = "form-group">
  <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
  <input className="form-control" type="email" name="email" defaultValue={emailx} ref = {this.emailInput}/>
  </div>
  <div className = "form-group">
  <label htmlFor="contact">Contact</label>
  <input className="form-control" type="text" name="phone" defaultValue={phonex} ref = {this.phoneInput} />
  </div>
  <div className = "form-group">

  <input className="btn btn-primary btn-block" type="submit" name="editor" value="Edit" />
  </div>
  </form>
  </div>
  </div>
)   } } const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({   edits: state.Users.editor }) export default connect(mapStateToProps, {get_contact,update_contact})(Edit);
```

Comment: it seems that the data is always one step behind? Is that accurate

Comment: what do you mean because when i check my editor object in store, the data is always updated and the diff in redux dev tools clearly shows it

Comment: I am asking that since everything in redux is async, there is a chance that the render is completed before the state is changed. Could be in microseconds, but thats all it takes.